# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'trusted-types' in '' angular

Tags: angular, typescript, security, xss

getting Module not found:

> Error: Can't resolve 'trusted-types' installed trusted types using
> this command **npm i @types/trusted-types --force.** and npm install
> trusted-types --save.

Still getting the same error but I can see **trusted types** inside **node_modules/@types** folder.
below code is how I am using trusted types in code.

```js
import { trustedTypes } from 'trusted-types';
    function createDefaultTrustedType(){
        trustedTypes.createPolicy('default', {
            createHTML: (s) => { 
                return DOMPurify.sanitize(s)
             }
        });
    }
```

Comment: You cannot use this only by installing the types for it, you also need the actual package. Try `npm install trusted-types --save`.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the editor is laggy and doesn't recognize a package. For me a reopen solves.